# How to write query on the elements value in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a metrics called - kube_node_status_condition in which I have elements that have value 0 or 1.

[image]

I need to write the query in such a way that it will only list the elements which has value 1. How to do so? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this table or something else?

Comment: This is the data returned by Prometheus metrics - has 2 sections - Element and value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
kube_node_status_condition==1
```